# Generate a random gaussian signal of 5000 samples

Tags: python, signals, histogram, gaussian, sample

I want to generate a random gaussian signal of 5000 samples and calculate the standard deviation of it. After that, I want a see histogram graphics of it. I have tried a bunch of things from other related topics but none of them that I was looking for. Can anyone help me? by python btw

Comment: is that some data (5000 of it) with gaussian distribution?

Comment: i tried but name 'x' is not defined so cant plot histogram

Comment: x would be values, y would be their amount

Answer (score 0):

you can use the libraries numpy and matplotlib, that resolve all what you are trying to do:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#create signal
nSamples = 5000
randomSignal = np.random.randn(nSamples)
#calculate standard deviation 
std = np.std(randomSignal)


#generate an histogram
binNumber = 20
plt.hist(x,bins = binNumber)
```

hope this helps, if you are looking for other thing let me know (sorry for potato english)